# Crashlytics for NDK not finding tombstone

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have Crashlytics working for Java crashes.  I'm trying to get it to work for NDK/C++ crashes.   Followed instructions and read every post out there that I can find.  Lot's of other problems, but what I get in logcat is:

```
   I/CrashlyticsInitProvider: CrashlyticsInitProvider skipping
   initialization D/libcrashlytics: Initializing libcrashlytics version 2.0.5 
   D/libcrashlytics: Initializing native crash handling successful.
   I/CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics Core 2.7.0.33
   W/CrashlyticsCore: **No minidump data found in directory \
        /data/user/0/jp.yyyyyy.app.zzzzz/files/.Fabric/\
        com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-ndk/native/1578934298647**
```

The contents of my build.gradle have the following:

```
dependencies {
    ....
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.1.1'
}
```

Interestingly, these dependency version numbers don't match what the logcat output indicates.

Further, I don't see a C++ stack trace in the logcat either.

Is there some way to enable the creation of tombstone files?

Comment: Did you see: [Get Android NDK crash reports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/ndk-reports). Your library versions seem older than current recommendation.

Comment: Edited post to include my dependency info.   Interestingly, the version number don't match between build.gradle and the logcat output.  Does that seem wrong to others?